# flask - problem with multiple post request methods

Tags: python, mysql, flask, werkzeug

I have a page with a search bar that is connected to my database and I am creating a button where the user will be able to update the database by uploading .xlsx file.

I wrote scripts and functions but when I click Submit button I get this error:

`werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'product'`

Everything works ok when I run python function from PyCharm or when I delete `search_bar` function in main.py and then run the function but it doesn't work if I have `search_bar` function at all.

Any idea why it isn't working?

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, send_file, send_from_directory, flash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import os

from compare import upload_excel_to_sql

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/content)
def content():
    # Check if user is loggedin
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        # User is loggedin show them the home page
        return render_template('content.html', username=session['username'])
    # User is not loggedin redirect to login page
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

# SEARCH IN DATABASE
@app.route('/content', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_bar():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        if request.method == "POST":
            cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
            product = request.form['product']
            # search by project name or title or brand
            cursor.execute("USE content_repository")
            cursor.execute("""SELECT upload_date, 
                                    product_code, 
                                    Project_name, 
                                    Country, 
                                    Brand, 
                                    Category, 
                                    Title, 
                                    Bullet_Points, 
                                    Description, 
                                    version 
                            FROM product WHERE Project_name LIKE %s OR Title LIKE %s OR Brand LIKE %s""",
                           (product, product, product))

            connection.commit()
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            # all in the search box will return all the tuples
            if len(data) == 0 and product == 'all':
                cursor.execute("""SELECT upload_date, 
                                    product_code, 
                                    Project_name, 
                                    Country, 
                                    Brand, 
                                    Category, 
                                    Title, 
                                    Bullet_Points, 
                                    Description, 
                                    version 
                                FROM product""")
                connection.commit()
                data = cursor.fetchall()
            return render_template('content.html', data=data)
        return render_template('content.html')
    return redirect((url_for('content')))


# UPLOADING AND PROCESSING FILE

UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/uploads/'
DOWNLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/downloads/'

# Allow user to upload only xlsx files'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'xlsx'}

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'] = DOWNLOAD_FOLDER
# Set up the maximum size of the file, in this case it is 10 mb
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 10 * 1024 * 1024


# Functions that check if an extension is valid
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/content_repository', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # check if the post request has the file part
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                flash('No file part')
                return redirect(request.url)
            file = request.files['file']
            # if user does not select file, browser also
            # submit an empty part without filename
            if file.filename == '':
                flash('No selected file')
                return redirect(request.url)
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
                # we call process_file function and pass the uploaded file path as an argument
                filename = upload_excel_to_sql(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename), UPLOAD_FOLDER)
                return redirect(url_for('content', filename=filename))
        return render_template('content.html', username=session['username'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

compare.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
from aifc import Error
import os


def upload_excel_to_sql(file_path, upload_folder):
    """
    Load data from excel to sql database
    :param path: path to excel with dataset (str)
    :return: True if everything is correct
    """
    output_path = os.path.join(upload_folder, file_path)
    df_scrapped_data = pd.read_excel(output_path)
    for column in df_scrapped_data.columns:
        if column.startswith("Unnamed"):
            df_scrapped_data.drop([column], inplace=True, axis=1)
    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{psw}@localhost/{db}".format(user="root", psw="root", db="content"))
    df_scrapped_data.to_sql('product', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    return engine
```

content.html
form element with search bar and with upload and submit elements.

```
          <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="product">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>

            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <p><input type="file" name="file"></p>
              <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
            </form>
```

Comment: To me it seems that you route both the search and the upload forms to the same route. However, when you upload a file, then you submit the 2nd form only, meaning there is no `product` parameter set, but your content route expects it.

Comment: @Shadow thanks a lot for advice. The solution was much simpler because I had to add function names from main.py in action attribute in form tag and it worked

Comment: The action attribute of the form tells what url (route) to submit it to. This is why I wrote that both seem to go the same way.